# Azure Data Factory (Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'expression'. Expected type is 'Bool'.)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm trying to add in a IF Condition activity two conditions.

I need something like this:

```
and(@equals(int(variables('IsRunning')),1),@equals(int(variables('IsRunning1')),1))
```

And I receive:

> Expression of type: 'String' does not match the field: 'expression'.
> Expected type is 'Bool'.

The problem is that my variables has the following definition:

```
@string(length(activity('Filter').output.value))
```

What causes this type error, and how is it fixed?

Comment: `and(@equals(int(variables('IsRunning')),1),@equals(int(variables('IsRunning1')),1))` Is this is the expression that you are using in if condition?

Comment: Not exatcly. As i need is to check the result of my two variables. I supposed that something like the expression that i have put works but my variables are string type. I need if variable 1 is 1 and variable 2 is 1 then true else false.

Comment: "I'm trying to add in a IF Condition activity two conditions." Please clarify what that means.

Answer (score 0):

When I used your expression `and(@equals(int(variables('IsRunning')),1),@equals(int(variables('IsRunning1')),1))` in if condition expression, I got same.

[image]

Here, your expression is not correct as per if condition. if condition expects a boolean value but as per the syntax of the expression it is a String value.

Change your dynamic content expression like below and it will work for you.

`@and(equals(int(variables('IsRunning')),1),equals(int(variables('IsRunning1')),1))`

Here my variables are of String type and values for them are `"1"` for both.

[image]

Now, you can see I am able to execute the if activity.

[image]

Give your activities inside True activities and False activities of if condition as per your requirement.